# How to wire a dynamic mono microphone with PAM8610 stereo audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, microphone

I am trying to make a audio amplifier with PAM8610. I have a dynamic mono microphone. In the PAM8610 official file they say that "**To use the PAM8610 with a single-ended source, acground the INP input through a capacitor equal in value to the input capacitor on INN and
apply the audio source to the INN input. In a single-ended input application, the INP input should be acgrounded at the audio source other than
at the device input for best noise performance**"

The basic thing I want to know is how to ground INP and which capacitors to be used. And after that how to connect wires to potentiometer or directly amplifier.

How can I wire a dynamic mono microphone with PAM8610 stereo audio amplifier?

Comment: I would think both INP's are joined and INN's are AC ground as well to get mono

Comment: look at the first page of the datasheet

Comment: Not my business, but this amp has max. voltage gain only about 40. It's told as decibels in the beginning of the datasheet. To get 10W to a 8 ohm speaker you need input voltage about 0,22V. That's not anything unusual when one speaks of the expected input to a speaker amp module for the rated maximum output power. A dynamic mic outputs that much only if placed next to rock drummer's snare or someone screams the mic placed inside his mouth. A normal speech makes the mic output much less if the distance to the mic is say 3 inches - you need a mic preamp to amplify speech or singing.

Comment: The PAM8610 datasheet says, "Not recommended for new designs". With a 12V supply its maximum output is 10 very distorted Whats, or 5 low distortion Watts into 8 ohms per channel. If you risk using its maximum allowed supply of 15V then it produces 15 low distortion Watts per channel into 8 ohms but it will need a heatsink. Its input is line level, not mic level and needs a mic preamp.

Comment: I tried joining L and R and it is working but output is not enough as user287001 wrote. It seems that I'll need an active mic or change the amplifier chip to get good results. Thank you all guys... :)